# Techniques to optimize model to present the reason of infeasibility

Tags: linear-programming

I want to understand what are the techniques one can explore to debug linear programming related optimization problem which is turning out to be infeasible.

It turns out infeasible saying so and so equations lead to infeasibility but the problem is that the equation is formed using multiple inputs and has a logic behind it. How do I know which exact input caused the resultant equation to be such that it leads to infeasibility

Comment: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/1215/infeasibility-in-mathematical-optimization-models